# Assigning part of a string to a char * in C

Tags: c, string

I want to copy X to Y words of a string to the out char * array.

```
unsigned char * string = "HELLO WORLD!!!" // length 14
unsigned char out[9];
size_t length = 9;
for(i=0 ;i < length ;++i)
{
   out[i] = string[i+3];
}

printf("%s = string\n%s = out\n", string, out);
```

When looking at the output of `out`, why is there gibberish after a certain point of my string? I see the string of out as `LO WORLD!@` . Why are there weird characters appearing after the content I copied, isn't out supposed to be a an array of 9? I expected the output to be

```
LO WORLD!
```

Comment: So you want `strncpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor point, but string literals have type `char*` (or `const char*` in C++), not `unsigned char*` -- these might be the same in your implementation, but they don't need to be.

Furthermore, this is not true:

```
unsigned char * string = "HELLO WORLD!!!" // length 14
```

The string actually occupies **15** bytes -- there is an extra, hidden `'\0'` at the end, called a `nul` byte, which marks the end of the string. These nul terminators are very important, because if they're not present, then many C library functions which manipulate strings will keep going until they hit a byte with a value equal to `'\0'` -- and so can end up reading or trampling over bits of memory they shouldn't do. This is called a **buffer overrun**, and is a classic bug (and exploitable security problem) in C programmes.

In your example, you haven't included this nul terminator in your copied string, so `printf()` just keeps going until it finds one, hence the gibberish you're seeing. In general, it's a good idea only to use C library functions to manipulate C strings if possible, as these are careful to add the terminator for you. In this case, `strncpy` from `string.h` does exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

In C you need to terminate your string with a 0x00 value so a string of length 9 needs ten bytes to store it with the last set to 0.  Otherwise your print statements run off into random data.

```
unsigned char * string = "HELLO WORLD!!!" // length 14
unsigned char out[10];
size_t length = 9;
for(i=0 ;i < length ;++i)
{
   out[i] = string[i+3];
}
out[length] = 0x00;

printf("%s = string\n%s = out\n", string, out);
```

Answer (score 1):

C strings must be null terminated.  You only created an array large enough for 8 characters + the null terminator, but you never added the terminator.

So, you need to allocate the length plus 1 and add the terminator.

```
// initializes all elements to 0
char out[10] = {0};
// alternatively, add it at the end.
out[9] = '\0';
```

Think of it this way; you're passed a `char*` which represents a string. How do you know how long it is?  How can you read it?  Well, in C, a sentinel value is added to the end.  This is the null terminator.  It is how strings are read in C, and passing around unterminated strings to functions which expect C strings results in undefined behavior.

And then... just use `strncpy` to copy strings.

Answer (score 1):

A 9 character string needs 10 bytes because it must be null ( 0 ) terminated. Try this:

```
unsigned char out[10]; // make this 10
size_t length = 9; 
for(i=0 ;i < length ;++i)
{
   out[i] = string[i+3];
}
out[i] = 0; // add this to terminate the string
```

A better approach would be just the line:

```
   strncpy(out, string+3, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have copy 9 characters from your string, you'll need to have an array of 10 to do that. It is because a C string needs to have '\0' as null terminated character. So your code should be rewritten like this:

```
unsigned char * string = "HELLO WORLD!!!" // length 14
unsigned char out[10];
size_t length = 9;
for(i=0 ;i < length ;++i)
{
   out[i] = string[i+3];
}
out[9] = 0;

printf("%s = string\n%s = out\n", string, out);
```